# Run containers on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I am trying to use the newly launched service i.e. running containers on AWS lambda. But since this whole idea is quite new I am unable to find much support online.

**Question:** Is there a programmatic way to publish a new ECR image into lambda with all the configurations, using AWS SDK (preferably python)?

Also, can it directly be published version instead of

```
def pushLatestAsVesion(functionArn, description="Lambda Eenvironment"):
    functionDetails = client.get_function(FunctionName=functionArn)
    config = functionDetails['Configuration']
    response = client.publish_version(
        FunctionName=functionArn,
        Description=description,
        CodeSha256=functionDetails['Configuration']['CodeSha256'],
        RevisionId=functionDetails['Configuration']['RevisionId']
    )
    print(response)
pushLatestAsVesion('arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:*************:function:my-serverless-fn')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SDK, but please check SAM - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-container-image-support-for-aws-lambda-with-aws-sam/